# How is the references created to fsc when building a F# project?

Tags: f#, msbuild, teamcity, paket

We have a F#-project that fails to build on teamctiy and can't figure out the solution to it. It seems like when building through teamcity the arguments to fsc is not correct for us. If I run `msbuild /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release` manually on the same source it all work just fine.

I'll provide the content of the failing fsproj-file to show what I mean (it's not a large project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>3e68783b-823c-4394-85cb-4a05aa3f3722</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>SFag.DataRepository</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>SFag.DataRepository</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFSharpCoreVersion>4.4.0.0</TargetFSharpCoreVersion>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Name>Sfag.DataRepository</Name>
    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <Tailcalls>false</Tailcalls>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>3</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\SFag.DataRepository.XML</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <Tailcalls>true</Tailcalls>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>3</WarningLevel>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\SFag.DataRepository.XML</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AssemblyInfo.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Tilsynsmyndighet.fs" />
    <None Include="Script.fsx" />
    <None Include="paket.references" />
    <Compile Include="KonsesjonRepository.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Sfag.Contracts\Sfag.Contracts.csproj">
      <Name>Sfag.Contracts</Name>
      <Project>{260b3032-028d-417e-acde-1c332744b1bf}</Project>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(MinimumVisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '11.0'">
      <PropertyGroup Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets')">
        <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <PropertyGroup Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets')">
        <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
  <Import Project="$(FSharpTargetsPath)" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier) == '.NETFramework' And $(TargetFrameworkVersion) == 'v4.6.1'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="FSharp.Core">
          <HintPath>..\packages\FSharp.Core\lib\net40\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>True</Private>
          <Paket>True</Paket>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier) == '.NETFramework' And $(TargetFrameworkVersion) == 'v4.6.1'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="FSharp.Data.SqlClient">
          <HintPath>..\packages\FSharp.Data.SqlClient\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.SqlClient.dll</HintPath>
          <Private>True</Private>
          <Paket>True</Paket>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="System.Data">
          <Paket>True</Paket>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="System.Xml">
          <Paket>True</Paket>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
</Project>
```

When running `msbuild` manually we get the correct arguments to `fsc.exe`:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe -o:obj\Release\SFag.DataRepository.dll --debug:pdbonly --noframework --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Release\SFag.DataRepository.XML --optimize+ -r:E:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\cd80d924274f60cd\src\packages\FSharp.Core\lib\net40\FSharp.Core.dll -r:E:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\cd80d924274f60cd\src\packages\FSharp.Data.SqlClient\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.SqlClient.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\mscorlib.dll" -r:E:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\cd80d924274f60cd\src\Sfag.Contracts\bin\Release\Sfag.Contracts.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Core.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Numerics.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.dll" --target:library --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --fullpaths --flaterrors --subsystemversion:6.00 --highentropyva+ "C:\Users\admtoja1\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1.AssemblyAttributes.fs" AssemblyInfo.fs Tilsynsmyndighet.fs KonsesjonRepository.fs
```

When teamcity runs the build we don't get the exact same output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe -o:obj\Release\SFag.DataRepository.dll --debug:pdbonly --noframework --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Release\SFag.DataRepository.XML --optimize+ -r:E:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\cd80d924274f60cd\src\packages\FSharp.Core\lib\net40\FSharp.Core.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\mscorlib.dll" -r:E:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\cd80d924274f60cd\src\Sfag.Contracts\bin\Release\Sfag.Contracts.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Core.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Data.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Numerics.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Xml.dll" --target:library --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --fullpaths --flaterrors --subsystemversion:6.00 --highentropyva+ "E:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\temp\buildTmp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1.AssemblyAttributes.fs" AssemblyInfo.fs Tilsynsmyndighet.fs KonsesjonRepository.fs
```

The error is that in the Teamcity version there is no reference to `FSharp.Data.SqlClient`. This is really strange since I thought teamcity would just call `msbuild` on my solution.

Answer (score 0):

FSharp.Data.Client is coming from a NuGet package and I would have a guess that NuGet packages are not being restored correctly prior to the compilation step.

Enable NuGet on TeamCity through the Administration link

[image]

Add a NuGet install step prior to the compilation step

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: We are using paket to handle all the packages, and this was related to that.

Comment: Awesome, glad it pointed you in the right direction. I'm now googling paket :)

Comment: You should definitely lookup paket, https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/. Helps you to deal with version conflicts between nuget packages, and also lets you have references to other things than nuget packages.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a newbie paket mistake. Since we want to have automatic resolve of the packages when we build in Visual Studio we must add one line to our project files:

```
<Import Project="..\.paket\paket.targets" />
```

And it also important that this file is in the right place in the project file. If I had it above

```
<Import Project="$(FSharpTargetsPath)" />
```

it didn't work. So I put it right below and now everything works like a charm.